# Typescript: type for named arrow function throws TS error for spyOn() in Jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have this arrow method in my Angular comp

```
private event_listener_callback = (evt: Event): void => {
   // do something
}
```

All working so far.

In a Jasmine unit test where I spy on that arrow function via

```
spyOn(comp, 'event_listener_callback').and.callThrough();
```

it throws error `TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

using `@ts-ignore` avoids that and the unit test is working correctly.

What would be the correct type for the arrow function to avoid this TS error ?

Comment: Why do you need to spy on a private method

Comment: The type should be  private propertyname: (evt: Event)=> void

Comment: the type you suggested does not resolve the TS error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to set the property to public for the TS error to go away...